# 2D Array Memory Leak - Should be easy, I feel stupid

Tags: c++, c, memory, 2d

Very simple code:

```
signed int **ifftResults = (signed int **)malloc(sizeof(signed int *) * recordsPerBuffer);

for (int i=0; i < recordsPerBuffer; i++)
{
    ifftResults[i] = (signed int*)malloc(sizeof(signed int) * fftLength);
}
```

Then later:

```
for (int i=0; i < recordsPerBuffer; i++)
{
   free(ifftResults[i]);
}
free(ifftResults);
```

When I comment these lines out - no memory leak.  When they are present - memory leak.  Hopefully I just need another pair of eyes, cause I cannot for the life of me see what's wrong.

Comment: No, there's no memory leak there. Your problem must be somewhere else. First question, if you comment out the above lines, how do you know there's a memory leak. How are you measuring it?

Comment: Sounds contradictory!  How are you establishing that the leak occurs? How are you ensuring that you're testing the correct versions - rather than spotting the leak when they're commented out and missing the leak when they're present?  How big is the leak?  How big is `recordsPerBuffer`?  How big is `fftLength`?  Is there any chance that `recordsPerBuffer` changes between allocation and release?  The question was tagged C++; why were you not using `new`, or even `std::vector`?

Comment: How can you say that without those rows you have a leak?

Comment: It's an MFC application, the function that contains this code is called when I click a button.  I have Windows Task Manager open and when the code is not commented out the memory used by the process increases (in a non-regular way).  When the code is commented out the memory increases for two clicks (I don't know why) and then stays steady.

Comment: I agree with john there doesn't seem to be a memory leak there. Maybe completely off the mark, but have you checked the value of recordsPerBuffer doesn't change between the aloc and the dealloc?

Comment: @Russbear: Task Manager is actually a very bad way to measure the actual amount of resources your code uses. The operating system may do lots of things like caching and some other memory bookkeeping operations in the background that will skew the numbers.

Comment: @Russbear: It's an extremely common misunderstanding. Task manager is not a valid way to measure memory leaks. When you free memory it becomes available again to your application, it doesn't become available again to anyone. So task manager still shows it as assigned to your application.

Comment: Since you're using MFC, you must be using a C++ compiler. In C++ we have something called `std::vector` that's vastly superior to `malloc()`-ing 2D arrays. The equivalent would be something like `std::vector< std::vector<signed int> > ifftResults;` and you be able to almost never worry about memory leaks.

Comment: @Russbear: If you want memory to be really freed back to Windows, then you have to look at the Windows API. `VirtualAlloc` I think is function you need.

Comment: @john: Okay - I gotcha.  Thanks for clearing that up for me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code presented as I'm writing this doesn't seem to be sufficient to answer the question of "why".

However, since you're using C++ you can make sure that there's no memory leak by using `std::vector`.

Like so:

```
// Allocation.
std::vector< std::vector< int > >  fftResults( recordsPerBuffer, std::vector< int >( fftLength ) );

// Usage:
fftResults[y][x] = blah;

// Deallocation: automatic.
```

Another way to implement a matrix is like

```
std::vector< int >  fftResults( recordsPerBuffer*fftLength );
```

and then compute the index for given (x,y).

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: That should be `std::vector< int >( fftLength )` and `recordsPerBuffer*fftLength`.